# Reading out a json file on specific values in Java

Tags: java, android

I've been struggling with the reading of a certain value in a JSON file. So I want to use the values of "indices" but I dont know exactly on how to retrieve it. I've tried to look for it on google but I couldnt find an explanation that I could understand. This is what I got so far from just reading it. (the object variable is the whole JSONObject that I parsed from the file.

```
JSONArray arr = object.getJSONObject("statuses").getJSONObject("entities").getJSONArray("hashtags");
```

And this is the JSON part that I need, I need to somehow get the indices object and turn it into an int array.

```
{
      "statuses": [{
        "created_at": "Wed Apr 20 13:01:49 +0000 2016",
        "id": 722772259073626100,
        "id_str": "722772259073626112",
        "text": "RT @SaxionUAS: Why study in #Holland? Check this video by Study in Holland!\n\n#studyinholland #saxion",
        "entities": {
          "hashtags": [{
            "text": "Holland",
            "indices": [
              28,
              36
            ]
          }, {
            "text": "studyinholland",
            "indices": [
              77,
              92
            ]
          }, {
            "text": "saxion",
            "indices": [
              93,
              100
            ]
          }],
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what about `object.getJSONArray()` ... ?

Comment: Yes what about it?

Comment: By looking at json you provided, it looks like `statuses` is array instead of JSONObject. Am I right?

Comment: indices not seems to be a josn array but an ordinary array. So get it as an object and cast it to an array Array arr=....

Comment: @AliSheikhpour It is a JSON array... What part of it makes you think it isn't?

Comment: Yes it is, though I noticed when I made the start like object.getJSONArray("statuses")... I can only do with indexes instead of names, I didnt know how else to do it.

Comment: There's a length method on the array. That should help you make a loop over the indices

Comment: you use `object.getJSONObject()` instead of `object.getJSONArray()`. that's what's up about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the indices array, you may use

```
JSONArray arr = object.getJSONArray("statuses").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("entities").getJSONArray("hashtags").getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("indices");
```

The first index is 0, because we want the first element of the "statuses" array, the second index may range from 0 to 2, depending on which "indices" you want to reach.
Once you have a JSONArray, you can either use its `toList()` method to obtain a classical `java.lang.ArrayList` or this function converts directly to an int array:

```
int[] convert(JSONArray arr){
    int[] result = new int[arr.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
        result[i] = arr.getInt(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get statuses array
2. Loop over the objects of this array to get...
3. entries object + hashtag array
4. Loop over the objects this array to get the indices arrays

Happy coding!

Comment: Let me try this, so I already have like a statuses array loop, now the entries have to be cast as an JSONObject in which after that I need to go in there and cast the next hashtags to an JSONArray right?

Comment: There shouldn't need to be casting. The `getJsonObject(int index)` method should return a JSONObject. From that object, you call getJsonArray, then loop over that array

Comment: You could also look into Gson if you want a straight conversion to Java objects.  https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#object-examples

Comment: Well, its supposed to work without any other library, but I've made it to work, the only thing I'd need to do is cast the last indices to an int array, I assume I can do that by a cast to that like (int[]) from getString("indices")?

Comment: Indices is an array just like the previous ones you've gotten it just doesn't have objects, only ints, so getString isn't correct. I'm not too sure you can directly cast a JSONArray to an `int[]` so you may need another loop to populate your own int array